# How to use href="javascript:window.open..." in Angular JS?

Tags: javascript, html, angularjs

I am trying to use an  tag in HTML to open a new modal browser window with a url that is retrieve through an Angular value, as so:

```
<a href="javascript:OpenPopUpPage('{{listing.Linktest}}');">Test Link</a>
```

The rest of my angular markup works just fine, but the above anchor does not work.  In several attempts I'm made, I either don't get a value at all (null), or the resulting URL is marked as "unsafe".

I've tried calling a method within my controller to pass back the value, but same failures.

Am I going about this the wrong way?

Note:  OpenPopUpPage is a built-in SharePoint function that I'm using, but I could just as well call window.open or something else.  But I think that is immaterial to this problem.

UPDATE:  I have create a jsfiddle (warning, first-timer), and attempted to follow a couple of the responses here as a demo, but I can't get any of them to work correctly.  [My jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/planetparker28/7z7uttnb/5/)

Comment: Can you please make up a fiddle and share us the link to check your code?

Comment: Might I suggest not using `javascript:`?  It will make things easier... a lot less extra escaping to do.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you have isn't a normal link. It's more of a `<button>`, although it could go either way.

The angular way of handling the click to open a new window would then be:

```
<button type="button" ng-click="$ctrl.click($event)">...</button>
```

and in your angular code:

```
function Controller/Copmponent/Directive/Whatever() {
    this.url = 'http://example.com';
    this.click = function () {
        open(this.url, this.target, this.options);
    };
}
```

---

If your page needs to support JavaScript disabled, or if you weren't in angular land at all, it may be reasonable to use an `<a>` element provided that you give the `href` a valid URL:

```
<a href="{{$ctrl.url}}" ng-click="$ctrl.click($ctrl.url, $event)">...</a>
```

Comment: Thank you for your response.  I attempted to use your response in this jsfiddle.  Can you see where I'm going wrong?  http://jsfiddle.net/planetparker28/7z7uttnb/5/

Comment: Thanks for the code sample @zzzzBov.  I like the solution much better.  But how can I take that sample and make it so that the URL isn't hard-coded into the controller, but rather passed into the controller via an angular value that is coming from my REST call?  I attempted to update the fiddle to show what I mean, but broke it :-)

Comment: add `ng-if="{{$ctrl.url}}"` on the button, and use an AJAX call to assign the data in the controller. At this point you may want to do more research for other similar SO questions, and if they don't exist: ask a new one.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but I'm afraid that is beyond my current experience level.  However, since you did indeed provide a way to open a popup window, I marked your answer as good.  I can't help but think that this should be easier though... :-}

Comment: Figured it out, using mostly your code, but then figured out how to pass value properly into your function.  (omitting {{}} was the trick)

Answer (score 0):

```
.controller('controllerName', ['$scope', '$window',
    function($scope, $window) {
        $scope.redirectToNewPage = function(){
            $window.open('https://www.google.com', '_blank');
        };
    }
]);
```

Comment: call the function on click, <a href data-ng-click="redirectTonewPage()" >

Comment: Hello, thanks for the response.  It took me a bit to create a fiddle account and port a sample into it that actually worked.  Try this please:  http://jsfiddle.net/planetparker28/7z7uttnb/#&togetherjs=eyki4NOoQF

Comment: I added your code to my jsfiddle, but it didn't work.  Also, this code doesn't appear to support being passed a variable for the URL, since the value would be coming from a returned REST query, so I need to pass in something like {{mycontroller.myURL}} into this function.

Comment: @JimParker you can pass anything to the function in ng-click the whole expression is evaluated against the $scope I would stop trying to use javascript: in an href when you use ng-click it binds an event listener to the element when the click event happens it fires the function passed to it on the scope for the element and evaluates any arguments against the scope.

Comment: Try this please it is working as I have mentioned above code..https://jsfiddle.net/satyendon/nyvcz8va/

Answer (score 0):

I wanted to add this final answer, since while others provide good examples for opening pop-ups or new windows, the main objective was to be able to open a new window to a location that was passed from an angular/REST query value.

The answer was 2-part:

1) Use ng-click along with a function/method inside of your controller to handle the opening of the new window.  Avoid trying to use javascript directly within the .  Thanks all who contributed to this lesson for me.
2) Also, when passing a value to a function that is coming from your controller query output, don't include the {{}} around your passed value, as apparently that is only for diaplaying data, not passing it.

So here's the resulting code:

```
//HTML:
    <button type="button" ng-click="foo(myController.LinkValue)">Let's Do This</button>

//Code within Controller:
$scope.foo = function(myURL) {
    open(myURL, 'popup', 'width=300,height=200');
        };
```